# Hello, i just discovered collating sequence in regex in php but it not working for me

Tags: php, regex, character-class

This is the error: Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: POSIX collating elements are not supported at offset 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 73

This is the code:

```
$string = "AishahAishahAishah, RukoyyahRukoyyahRukoyyah and KafayahKafayahKafayah";
preg_match("/[.Aishah.]+/", $string, $array);
print_r($array);
```

Comment: Right, but you wanted `/(?:Aishah)+/`, didn't you?

Comment: i want to make "Aishah" to act has a single character so that, "Aishah{2}" for instance will means "AishahAishah"

Comment: You can't make it a single char, since it is not, but you may just use a group and quantify the group.

Comment: Definitely i dont understand the book by o'reily, i saw this in the book:Some locales consider certain character sequences as if they were a single character—
these are called collating sequences. To match one of these multicharacter sequences in
a character class, enclose it with [. and .]. For example, if your locale has the collating
sequence ch, you can match s, t, or ch with this character class:
[st[.ch.]]

Comment: You misunderstood this text. You can't define any text as a single char.